# Keep the nature of array formulas when using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula, openpyxl

Iam working on a excel workbook that needs to find median of all column values where another column value is a specific string using openpyxl. For this purpose, I have used `MEDIAN` and `IF` combined, where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> needs to be pressed for it to be considered as an Array formula.

But openpyxl doesn't keep this array formula's nature while saving the file.

**Example Data:**

```
Values | IDS
3.5    |  1234    
2.5    |  1234    
6.5    |  5687    
7.5    |  1234    
9.5    |  1234    
1.0    |  7894
```

For the above data, I should be able to only find median of values whose adjacent id=1234.

I have to use openpyxl and so need a non-array formula to loop through list of arrays with ids and find the medians of each matching id.

Answer (score 2):

openpyxl supports limited parsing of formulas embedded in cells. The openpyxl.formula package contains a Tokenizer class to break formulas into their constituent tokens. A token in an Excel formula.

> Tokens have three attributes:
>
> - value: The string value parsed that led to this token (The actual formula, in our Median-IF formula as you would write in excel.)
> - type: A string identifying the type of token
> - subtype: A string identifying subtype of the token (optional, and defaults to “”)

Your Median-If formula could be different, the code below is for reference only. It suggest how to parse (or say, validate) the array formulas using openpyxl. Usage is as follows:

```
>>> from openpyxl.formula import Tokenizer
>>> tok = Tokenizer("""{=MEDIAN(IF($B$1:$B$6="1234",$A$1:$A$6,""))}""")
>>> tok.type = Token.ARRAY
>>> tok.parse()
```

Kindly note that openpyxl support either the formula or the value of the formula which one can select using the *data_only* flag when opening a workbook. However, openpyxl does not and will not calculate the result of a formula. Use either of the following for a greater control to Excel in Python:

1. [pycel](https://pypi.org/project/pycel/)
2. [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html)

Attribution: openpyxl documentation ([Tokenizer](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formula.html?highlight=Tokenizer))

Comment: I guess flower braces here are giving me error. I have to use openpyxl for some reason, and would there not be any other way to solve this issue ?Lmk if there is any other solution in openpyxl