# How to insert array formula in an Excel sheet with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

I'm using OpenPyxl to create and modify an Excel sheet.
I have the following formula in Excel:

```
=(SUM(IF(LEFT(Balances!$B$2:$B$100,LEN($B4))=$B4,Balances!$D$2:$D$100)))
```

This formula which is an "array formula" is working but in order to write it by hand, I have to finish with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (because it's an array formula).
This transform then the formula as follow:

```
{=(SUM(IF(LEFT(Balances!$B$2:$B$100,LEN($B4))=$B4,Balances!$D$2:$D$100)))}
```

I want to be able to write this formula via OpenPyxl with the following code:

```
    sheet.cell(row=j, column=i).value = '{=(SUM(IF(LEFT(Balances!$B$2:$B$100,LEN($B4))=$B4,Balances!$D$2:$D$100)))}'
```

However, it doesn't work. OpenPyxl can't manage it. It give me the formula written but not working.

I could do it with XLSX Writer
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_array_formula.html

However XLSX writer doesn't work with already created files.

I don't see which path to follow.

Comment: I already saw this post but don't understand how to make it work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488989/keep-the-nature-of-array-formulas-when-using-openpyxl

Answer (score 6):

Use the `worksheet.formula_attributes` to set the array formula. Place the formula in the desired cell, A1 for this example. Then set the `formula_attributes` to the cell range you want to apply the formula to.

```
ws["A1"] = "=B4:B8"
ws.formula_attributes['A1'] = {'t': 'array', 'ref': "A1:A5"}
```

Comment: please, can you explain, how the attribute `ref` work?
I've put for example a formula `ws['D1'] = "=SUM(A1:A5*B1:B5)"` and then `ws.formula_attributes['D1'] = {'t': 'array', 'ref': "D1:D1"}`. This worked, but can I always set `ref` to the cell's coordinate?

Comment: I've found a description of the `ref` attribute [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellformula?view=openxml-2.8.1) "Range of cells which the formula applies to.[...]" but this doesn't helps me so much :)

Answer (score 1):

In case solution provided above does not work, check whether you are using english name of functions in your formulae.

In my case I have been using czech function name and although formulae works if inserted manually, it did not work when inserted via openpyxl.

**Switching to english name of the function solved the issue!**

Answer (score 1):

Update: Version 3.1 added support for legacy style arrays (no dynamic array support yet).  See [Openpyxl docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/simple_formulae.html)

This removes the need to use

> ws.formula_attributes

You still need to know how large the result set is. If you are using   say FILTER you need to add a prefix like this

> formula=formula.replace('FILTER','_xlfn._xlws.FILTER')

---

Original comment:

In my case the formula was using arrays for intermediate results before summarizing with a MAX.  The formula worked OK when typed in but not when inserted via openpyxl.  Office 365 version of Excel was inserting the new implicit intersection operator, @, incorrectly.

```
formula: ="Y" & MAX(tbl_mcare_opt[Year]*(tbl_mcare_opt[Who]=[@Who])*(tbl_mcare_opt[Year]<=intyear(this_col_name())))
```

It turns out that the properties needed to be set, as above. This allowed Excel to correctly interpret the formula. In my case the **ref** turned out to be just the single cell address.

I was able to determine that the formula was using dynamic arrays with a regex. If it was then I added the formula properties.

```
        # provision for dynamic arrays to be included in formulas - notify excel
        if is_formula(values[cn]):
          regex_column=r'[A-Za-z_]+(\[\[?[ A-Za-z0-9]+\]?\])'
          pattern=re.compile(regex_column)
          matches=pattern.findall(values[cn]) 
          if len(matches): # looks like a dynamic formula
            address=get_column_letter(cix)+str(rix)
            ws.formula_attributes[address]={'t':'array','ref': address}
```