# Openpyxl: How to remove the '@' symbol appearing in excel formulae when using Python

Tags: python, excel-formula, openpyxl

I'm trying to use a formula in Excel using Python and the [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library. The aim is to output the following into an excel cell.

`=SMALL(IF(G4:BI4>BJ4,G4:BI4),1)`

However, when I output the above in excel, the end result has an '@' symbol.

`=SMALL(IF(@G4:BI4>BJ4,G4:BI4),1)`

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
col_num += 1
cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
cell.value = f"=SMALL(IF({var_first}:{var_last}>{lowest_offer_cell},{var_first}:{var_last}),1)"
```

How do I get rid of the '@' symbol and get the correct output?

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298554/how-to-insert-array-formula-in-an-excel-sheet-with-openpyxl/57441549#57441549

Comment: The `@` symbol is something Excel uses for certain kinds of formulae. You'll need to check the Excel documentation and possibly reverse engineer the code if this isn't what you want.

Comment: @Redox: Yes, that link helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert array formula in an Excel sheet with openpyxl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298554/how-to-insert-array-formula-in-an-excel-sheet-with-openpyxl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question based on suggestions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298554/how-to-insert-array-formula-in-an-excel-sheet-with-openpyxl).

I added one line to my code.

```
col_num += 1
cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
cell.value = f"=SMALL(IF({var_first}:{var_last}>{lowest_offer_cell},{var_first}:{var_last}),1)"
worksheet.formula_attributes[cell.coordinate] = {'t': 'array', 'ref': f"{cell.coordinate}:{cell.coordinate}"}
```

I set the `worksheet.formula_attributes` to an array formula, then set the `ref` to the cell's coordinate. Now when I generate the Excel file, the '@' symbol is not included.