# Using openpyxl to insert formula with intermediate arrays

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a python script that I am programming to clear a sheet's table of all its contents then have the script insert a formula into a cell in a table.  The problem I believe is that the latter portion of the code needs to perform multiple intermediate array calculations.

Below is the Excel formula I would like to put in a cell in table:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH([[#This Row],[ID]],Table1[ID],0)),"NEEDS CARD",IF(ISBLANK([[#This Row],[DATE '[Ctrl+;']]]),"INPUT DATE",IF([[#This Row],[DATE '[Ctrl+;']]]>MAX(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(HSTACK(Table1[ID],Table1[RENEWAL DATE]),Table1[ID]=[[#This Row],[ID]]),2)),"EXPIRED","VALID")))
```

I have consulted the post below and had tried to replicate the solutions by attempting to recall a table column array but I only received #REF errors, @ operators at the start of my code, or an error message stating that Excel had a problem with some content in my workbook.  Specifically, I had tried both the `array_formulae` attribute and the `ArrayFormula()` command to no avail.  For example, using a cutdown version of my code as shown below yields a "problem with some content" error in excel; the same error occurs even without the ArrayFormula command.

[How to insert array formula in an Excel sheet with openpyxl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298554/how-to-insert-array-formula-in-an-excel-sheet-with-openpyxl?newreg=390b153bfc6a4c5184824fa6651a00e8)

I expected it to insert just as any other of my formulas but I realize that this one is unique in its need to utilize array calculations.

```
wsmo['B2'] = ArrayFormula("B2",'=MAX(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(HSTACK(Table1[[#Data],[WM ID]],Table1[[#Data],[RENEWAL DATE]]),Table1[[#Data],[WM ID]]=[[#This Row],[WM ID]]),2))')
```

The formula I'd like to input does have many quotation marks and apostrophes, but I have already accounted for that when inputting the formula by concatenating it as multiple text strings.

If there is another easier way to insert this formula using a different package that I am not aware of then I am open to branching out.

I appreciate any and all help, thank you.

Update [answered]:
I opened the spreadsheet using 7zip and inspected the xml as suggested and found my formula written in the needed format and I applied the `ArrayFormula` reference to only one cell as suggested.
Thank you very much moken and Charlie Clark!

Comment: The Openpyxl [documents](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/simple_formulae.html#id1) explains how to do it. You have the format in the 2nd formula however applied to single cell rather than a range.

Comment: If you unzip the relevant source for the worksheet, you'll see how Excel writes the XML and that's the best way to do this kind of thing. `ArrayFormula` just make sure the correct attributes are written.